# Opening urls without opening tabs in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Basically I have a popup.html which takes certain inputs.
Those inputs are passed to background.js which then opens a url based on those inputs:

chrome.tabs.create({ url: urlToBeLoaded }); //code for opening url in background.js

then the content.js performs work on that loaded page and returns results to popup.html.

But the problem is when that line of background.js is executed;it opens that url in a new tab. I really don't want to show the user from where i am scraping the results.

Can i accomplish the task by not opening any tab in user's browser.
I cannot use iframe to open that url bcoz the website from which i am scraping information are highly secure and don't allow them to opened in iframes.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't simply XHR the data (because it's a dynamic page) and it cannot be opened in a frame inside your background page, you're out of luck.

A remote possibility is to have some server fetch and run the page with something like PhantomJS, but that's a solution outside an extension.

Comment: OP says "I cannot use iframe to open that url".

Comment: Correct, I noticed and say so in the answer (though I noticed it late). Might reformulate the question, it sounds bad now.